# Comparing supremum and infimum of sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $(b_n)$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ two sequences and assume that $a_m ≤ b_m$ for all $m$.

Prove that:

(1) $\lim_{n\to \infty}{\inf[a_n]}\le\lim_{n\to \infty}{\inf[b_n]}$

(2) $\lim_{n\to \infty}{\sup[a_n]}\le\lim_{n\to \infty}{\sup[b_n]}$

Construct two sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that $a_n<b_n$ but $\lim_{n\to \infty}{\sup[a_n]}\lt\lim_{n\to \infty}{\sup[b_n]}$ is not true.

Any help with this question would be great.

Answer (score 0):

As for all $k \in \mathbb N$ you have $a_k \le b_k$, hence you also have for all $n \in \mathbb N$ $$\begin{cases}
\sup \{a_k : k \ge n\} \le \sup \{b_k : k \ge n\}\\
\inf \{a_k : k \ge n\} \le \inf \{b_k : k \ge n\}
\end{cases}$$ Hence results (1) and (2) based on the definition of $\limsup$ and $\liminf$.

For your last question, take $a_m=1-\frac{1}{m}$ and $b_m=1$

Comment: it should be less than for part 2 only

Comment: @babylon I updated my answer according to your question change.